# MongoDB Mapping classes

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Does MongoDB (specifically the Morphia ORM) support any class mapping features like gson's type adapter, I'm trying to map a class that contains some fields that I don't want to store.

Comment: Yes it does, via convenience of any 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate fields with `@Transient` and they won't get mapped.

Comment: I'm trying to map a class that I don't have the src to

Comment: Morphia doesn't support mapping 3rd party classes.